# How to serialize and deserialize python object to JSON without json library

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, serialization

My task is to create a JSON serialiser which can serialize different Python objects to JSON. So of course I can't use JSON library. But searching the information about serialisation gives something like "Use `import json` and be happy.

So can anybody give me some piece of advice of how to realize this task?

Comment: why can't you use the `json` module?

Comment: @rv.kvetch restriction given by task

Comment: well no offense, but that task sounds like it should perhaps reconsider. after all, `json` is in the standard library (stdlib).